# How to print shipping labels for multiple orders

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Converted html content into image format when html page is loaded, But can't able to convert html content into image when it is called from controller.(For convertion we are using HTML2CANVAS)

This is for a Linux server, PHP 7.2 and Codeigniter 3.1.5

We have found solution for load html page using below function:
In Javascript

```
$.each(data, function(key,value) {   //for select multiple datas
        var html = escape(value.design);     
        var orderid = value.orderid;
        var label_height = value.label_height;
        var label_width = value.label_width;
        $(".temp_div").load("<?php echo base_url();?>orders/downloadcavas?design="+html+"&orderid="+orderid+"&label_width="+label_width+"&label_height="+label_height);
    });
```

In Codeigniter

```
function downloadcavas()
{  
$data1['design'] = $design = urldecode($_GET["design"]);
$data1['orderid'] = $orderid = $_GET["orderid"];
$data1['label_width'] = $label_width =  $_GET["label_width"];
$data1['label_height'] = $label_height =  $_GET["label_height"]; 
if(isset($label_height))
{
if(isset($label_width))
{
$style = "height:".$label_height."in;width:".$label_width."in;";
}
else
{
$style = "height:".$label_height."in;";
}
}
else
{
$style = "";
} 
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url().'js/jquery-ui.css"><link href="'.base_url().'js/lable_design.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<style>
.canvas-section { 
background-color: #fff; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="divCanvas" class="canvas-section divCanvas" style="'.$style.'margin-top:-70px;"  >'.$design.' </div> 
<script type="text/javascript" >$("#preloader").hide(); 
$.getScript("'.base_url().'js/html2canvas.js"); 
setTimeout(function(){
preview1();
},1000); 
function preview1()
{        
var element = $(".divCanvas");  
var orderid = "'.$orderid.'"; 
var scaleBy = 5;
var w = 1000;    
var h = 1000;
var div = document.querySelector(".divCanvas"); 
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = w * scaleBy;
canvas.height = h * scaleBy;
canvas.style.width = w + "px";
canvas.style.height = h + "px";
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.scale(scaleBy, scaleBy);  
html2canvas(div, {
useCORS: true, 
canvas:canvas, 
onrendered: function (canvas) { 
theCanvas = canvas;
var image = theCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"); 
$.ajax({
url: "'.base_url().'template_builder/template/orderimagesave", 
data:"canvas="+image+"&orderid="+orderid,
type: "POST",  
cache: false,
global: false,
success: function(data){ }});
}
}); 
} </script> 
</body>
</html>'; 
}
```

But we cant able to convert images for continuous html content. Can you please suggest anyother method to convert html content into image without loading html page. 
Thanks in advance